# Gradle build fails after updating gradle to 2.3

Tags: java, gradle, testng

I was using gradle version 2.0 which was working fine but, after updating it to 2.3 I get this error.

` Exception thrown while executing model rule: org.gradle.api.publish.plugins.PublishingPlugin$Rules#publishing(org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionContainer)

> Cannot create a Publication named 'repositories' because this container does not support creating elements by name alone. Please specify which subtype of Publication to create. Known subtypes are: MavenPublication
>   `

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'java' 
//version extension.moduleVersion 
//apply plugin: 'maven-publish' defaultTasks = ['deploy'] 
/*  
* Task to generate Gradle Wrapper artifacts. This is  
* only required to update the wrapper itself and not  * needed for regular builds.
*/ 

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
            gradleVersion = '2.3'
            distributionUrl = 'http://x.x.x.x/eng/gradle/gradle-2.3-bin.zip' }

repositories {
        maven {
                 url "abc.com"
        }

}
```

Comment: Are you certain the script here is the actual one you are using? The error you are getting is regarding defining a Maven publication inside a `publishing { }` block. You can see by the error the exception is being thrown by the publishing plugin despite it clearly being commented out. Are you perhaps using any init scripts?

Comment: This script should works fine if you add correct urls. Did you try to call it explicitly like `gradlew -b build.gradle clean wrapper`?

Comment: Yes the urls are proper i also tried with this url  'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3-bin.zip' But still I'm getting the same error.